# Spring Boot OAuth character escape

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a java spring boot application with oauth.
To get a bearer i call my API and validate the login credentials.

Now there is a business case, where i have to throw a new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException in the AuthenticationManager and all the special characters (umlaute) always get escaped and i don't know why.

Throwing the Exception:

```
throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Error message with Ä Ö Ü ß");
```

And this is the output:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Error message with &Auml; &Ouml; &Uuml; &szlig;"
}
```

Someone has an idea where the problem could be?

Thank in advance

Comment: thanks for the answer.
my content type of the response is already "application/json;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Yes, your characters seem to be encoded correctly as UTF-8, as far as I can see. But your message is XML encoded. Is there any pipe in your request that interprets your content as text/html?

Comment: @Maximus I don't think so. also the translate methode in loggingExceptionTranslator in the Websecurity.java looks ok. When debugging, the message in the excbody looks ok, no characters escaped:

ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> responseEntity = super.translate(e);
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setAll(responseEntity.getHeaders().toSingleValueMap());
      OAuth2Exception excBody = responseEntity.getBody();
      return new ResponseEntity<>(excBody, headers, responseEntity.getStatusCode());

Comment: In the response header I can find the field "WWW-Authenticate" with value "Bearer error="unauthorized", error_description="Error message with Ä Ö Ü ß". So looks like the character escape only takes place in the response body. why?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with a work around:

```
@Component
public class CustomWebResponseExceptionTranslator extends DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator {
@Override
public ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> translate( Exception e ) throws Exception {
    ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> exception = super.translate( e );
    // Workaround to special characters
    exception.getBody().addAdditionalInformation( "error_description", exception.getBody().getMessage() );
    return exception;
}}
```

And config in AuthorizationServer:

```
endpoints.exceptionTranslator( customWebResponseExceptionTranslator );
```